# Can't create Word sub-documents when original file is in OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, master

If I have a local file, or a file on a mapped network drive, I can use the master document tools to split it (create sub-documents). If I have a file on my OneDrive, fully synched locally, Word doesn't throw an error but it also does NOT create the sub files in the location of the original file. Shouldn't this work the same way? Is it an issue with the way my OneDrive is setup?

Comment: See my webpage "Master Documents Feature in Microsoft Word" https://addbalance.com/word/masterdocuments.htm#PageStart. There is no way I would ever have such a construct in a cloud location. It is dangerous to your work even on a single hard drive in a single folder.

Comment: We only use it to split up one large file into several small ones, permanently. We don't keep them linked and never put them back together. I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel with a macro to break up a large file based on headings.

Comment: I suspect, but do not know, that the issue is with doing this on OneDrive (or SharePoint). This is an old and imperfect tool developed before there was any cloud storage. There have been pleas for more than twenty years to fix it without improvement. I would hope that if they do fix it to work with cloud storage, they would also fix the parts that destroy the work.